# Error with mysql_select_db when uploaded to server but not locally

Tags: php, sql

The below code woks on my local WAMP server, but when uploaded it returns this error:

**Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in index.php on line 26**

**Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: A link to the server could not be established in index.php on line 26
Error: Could not connect to the database. Please try again later.**

```
<?php
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
$dbhost = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = '';
if ($_POST)
{
    $email = trim($_POST['email']); 
    $ip_orig = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $ip = ip2long($ip_orig);
    $date = date('Y-m-d');  
    $time = date('H:i:s');  
    if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Please enter your email.";
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
    }
    if(!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", ($_POST['email']))) { 
        $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Incorrect email format; please try again.";
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit; 
    }
    $db = @mysql_pconnect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
    if(!$db){
        echo "Error: Could not connect to the database. Please try again later.";
    exit;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT newsletter_email FROM Newsletter WHERE newsletter_email='".$email."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Sorry, that email address is already in our database.";
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Newsletter(newsletter_email, newsletter_ip, newsletter_date, newsletter_time) VALUES('".$email."', '".$ip."', '".$date."', '".$time."')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Thanks! We will be in touch with you soon.";
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
    mysql_close($db);
}
?>
```

Comment: Probably because you're setting the host, username, password and DB name to empty strings...

Comment: Are you sure the MySQL service is running on the server?

Comment: I took of the password, username and host before posting.

Comment: Yes sql is running, I have other scripts connecting to the same sql server and using the same password, user, and db settings. Only this script has an error, although it works offline on my wamp server.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the db username, password, db name and host at the top of the script.

***UPDATED:***

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'dbuser';
$dbpass = 'pass';
$dbname = 'test';

if ($_POST)
{

    //Retrieve data from form and create variables
    $email = trim($_POST['email']); 
    $ip_orig = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $ip = ip2long($ip_orig);
    $date = date('Y-m-d');  
    $time = date('H:i:s');  

    //Validate data
    if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Please enter your email.";
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
    }

    if(!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", ($_POST['email']))) { 
        $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Incorrect email format; please try again.";
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit; 
    }

    //Log into the server
    $db = @mysql_pconnect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    //Select the database desired
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    //If no connection can be made, echo it out to the screen
    if(!$db){
        echo "Error: Could not connect to the database. Please try again later.";
    exit;
    }

    //Check to see that no duplicates exist in the database
    $sql = "SELECT newsletter_email FROM Newsletter WHERE newsletter_email='".$email."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Sorry, that email address is already in our database.";
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }

    //Place into database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Newsletter(newsletter_email, newsletter_ip, newsletter_date, newsletter_time) VALUES('".$email."', '".$ip."', '".$date."', '".$time."')";

    //Run query and get result back; shouldn't return anything
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    //Redirect user to successful registration page
    $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Thanks! We will be in touch with you soon.";
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;

    //Close the database connection
    mysql_close($db);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input name="email" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hostname `""` is treated as `"localhost"`, and wrong username/password gets `Access denied` error. So his settings shouldn't cause `Could not connect to the database` error.

Comment: If the server doesn't use local MySQL, or uses a nonstandard socket path, it could certainly cause that error.

Comment: You are wrong. Please double check because that's exactly the error that he will encounter.

Comment: I took of the password, username and host before posting.

Comment: Updated my answer above with the script. Check it out. Also, if it doesn't work in that case you've got a problem with your MySQL, so please make sure that it's running properly.

Comment: What have you changed? I see you copied the script from another post, which is what I did, but have you made other changes?

Comment: @duskwuff server uses host such as internal-db.gridserver.com, I am using the same authentication settings for another script and it works fine.

Comment: This script makes no difference I still get the same error. My sql is running fine, I have many other script also using the same authentication values and table, only this script is returning an error.